# action/dispatch not updating store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm a bit confused because this method of updating my store has worked for me in the past - Though the setup is a little different.

In its simplest form, my action gets called, but my dispatch seems to be getting neglected

(`reduxMulti` and `thunk` middleware are applied to my store which enables async and multiple actions to be dispatched. )

```
export function modalDocDeleteAction() {
    // This logs as expected
    console.log("MODAL/ACTIONS.JS // Document Delete Action Fired");
    return dispatch => {
        // We don't make it here :(
        console.log("MODAL/ACTIONS.JS // Document Delete Action Fired In Return");
        dispatch([{ type: MODAL_DOC_DELETE }, modalOpenAction()]);
    };
}
```

**Some random JS file:**

I can successfully fire my action if I dispatch as below, so I don't think it's anything to do with my setup:

```
import { modalDocDeleteAction } from "../presentation/modal/actions";
import store from "../container/store";

export function someFunction() {
    store.dispatch(modalDocDeleteAction());
});
```

**From component:** *(I've left comments in as I think I may need to use `mapStateToProps` in the future)*

When I try to dispatch from a component is where I seem to be having issues.  I'm confused as this method has worked for me previously...  But this is the first time I've tried to update my store to modify a component within another component (Hopefully that makes sense)

*Imports:*

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { modalDocDeleteAction } from "./modal/actions"; // This is the correct location
```

*Component:*

```
const ProdRow = ({ document, index, edit, view, promoteRevert, remove }) => {

    // I've removed a bunch of unnecessary stuff out of here.

    return (
        <TableRow>  
            <TableCell colSpan="2">         
                    <ActionsIcon
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                        width="16"
                        height="16"
                        viewBox="0 0 16 16"
                        onClick={modalDocDeleteAction} // This fires my console log (above), but never makes it to the actual dispatch
                    >
                        <path
                            id="cross"
                            d="M21,6.611,19.389,5,13,11.389,6.611,5,5,6.611,11.389,13,5,19.389,6.611,21,13,14.611,19.389,21,21,19.389,14.611,13Z"
                            transform="translate(-5 -5)"
                            fill="#3c3c3c"
                        />
                        <title>Delete</title>
                    </ActionsIcon>
                )}
            </TableCell>
        </TableRow>
    );
};
```

*Redux / Export:*

```
// const mapStateToProps = state => ({
//  modalTitle: state.modalReducer.modalTitle,
//  modalText: state.modalReducer.modalText,
//  closeText: state.modalReducer.closeText,
//  continueText: state.modalReducer.continueText,
//  completeAction: state.modalReducer.completeAction,
//  visible: state.modalReducer.visible
// });

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    modalDocDeleteAction: () => dispatch(modalDocDeleteAction())
});

export default connect(
    // mapStateToProps,
    null,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Results);
```

This is the exact setup I use to modify my modal component within itself - I think because I'm trying to update the store "externally" is where the problems are coming from.  Any help would be great as I'm very stuck!  Thanks!

---

### **Redux bits:**

**ACTIONS.js** *Removed excess code*

```
import {
    MODAL_OPEN,
    MODAL_CLOSE,
    MODAL_COMPLETE_USER_ACTION,
    MODAL_DOC_DELETE,
    MODAL_DOC_PUBLISH,
    MODAL_DOC_REVERT,
    MODAL_DOC_CREATE_EXIT,
    MODAL_DOC_EDIT_EXIT
} from "./actionTypes";

import store from "../../container/store";

export function modalOpenAction() {
    console.log("MODAL/ACTIONS.JS // Modal Open Action Fired");
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch({ type: MODAL_OPEN });
    };
}

export function modalDocDeleteAction() {
    console.log("MODAL/ACTIONS.JS // Document Delete Action Fired");
    console.log(store.getState());
    return dispatch => {
        console.log(
            "MODAL/ACTIONS.JS // Document Delete Action Fired In Return"
        );
        dispatch([{ type: MODAL_DOC_DELETE }, modalOpenAction()]);
    };
}
```

**REDUCER.js** *Removed excess code*

```
const initialState = {
    modalTitle: "Placeholder Title",
    modalText: "Placeholder Text",
    closeText: "Placeholder Close",
    continueText: "Placeholder Continue",
    visible: false,
    completeAction: false
};

function modalReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
    case "MODAL_OPEN":
        return {
            ...state,
            visible: true,
            completeAction: false
        };


    case "MODAL_DOC_DELETE":
        return {
            ...state,
            modalTitle: "Delete Document?",
            modalText:
                    "Deleting a document will permanently remove it from S3",
            closeText: "No, Keep Document",
            continueText: "Yes, Delete Document"
        };
```

**STORE.js**

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import reduxMulti from "redux-multi";
import notificationReducer from "../presentation/notification/reducer";
import modalReducer from "../presentation/modal/reducer";

const reducers = combineReducers({
    notificationReducer,
    modalReducer
});

const store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(thunk, reduxMulti));

console.log("STORE.JS // Default State:");
console.log(store.getState());

export default store;
```

---

### **Working example:**

Following the exact same process as above in my Modal component works as expected:

**Imports:**

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Button from "../../form/button";
import { modalCloseAction, modalCompleteUserAction } from "./actions";
```

**Component (Styled Components):**

```
function Component({ ...props }) {
    const {
        modalTitle,
        modalText,
        closeText,
        continueText,
        visible,
        modalCloseAction,
        modalCompleteUserAction
    } = props;

    console.log("MODAL.JSX // Modal State:");
    console.log(props);

    return (
        <div>
            <ModalContainer visible={visible}>
                <Overlay visible={visible} />
                <Modal visible={visible}>
                    <ModalTitle>{modalTitle}</ModalTitle>
                    <ModalText>{modalText}</ModalText>
                    <ModalButtons>
                        <ModalButton
                            buttonStyle="Back"
                            onClick={modalCloseAction}
                        >
                            {closeText}
                        </ModalButton>
                        <ModalButton
                            buttonStyle="Primary"
                            onClick={modalCompleteUserAction}
                        >
                            {continueText}
                        </ModalButton>
                    </ModalButtons>
                </Modal>
            </ModalContainer>
        </div>
    );
}
```

**Redux/Export**

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    modalTitle: state.modalReducer.modalTitle,
    modalText: state.modalReducer.modalText,
    closeText: state.modalReducer.closeText,
    continueText: state.modalReducer.continueText,
    completeAction: state.modalReducer.completeAction,
    visible: state.modalReducer.visible
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    modalCloseAction: () => dispatch(modalCloseAction()),
    modalCompleteUserAction: () => dispatch(modalCompleteUserAction())
});

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Component);
```

**Dispatch Actions:**

```
export function modalCloseAction() {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch({ type: MODAL_CLOSE });
    };
}

export function modalCompleteUserAction() {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch([{ type: MODAL_COMPLETE_USER_ACTION }, modalCloseAction()]);
    };
}
```

Comment: @DavinTryon that's right! - Updated my post

Comment: _"reduxMulti and thunk middleware are applied to my store which enables async and multiple actions to be dispatched."_ - can you show that code? My guessing is it's not, because `dispatch => { ... }` actions are generally handled by thunk middleware.

Comment: @James I've updated my post with my Action, Reducer and Store setup.  As I say, I've dispatched like this elsewhere and it's worked as expected. (Even the example in a js file at the start of my post)  This is the first time I've come into contact with this particular issue - This is the first time I've tried updating one component from another via redux dispatches though, so I feel like the issue might be in the component setup itself.   I'm new to this though, so I could be wrong.

Comment: so the example you show where it _does_ work is referencing the store directly, and the fact it works (and now having seen the store setup) would suggest the store is setup to handle async actions. Are you correctly setting the `Provider` in your component hierarchy, see this [example](https://react-redux.js.org/api/provider#example-usage).

Comment: @James Yep!  My provider wraps the app which contains everything else on the page

`<Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>`

Comment: @James I've included a working example of my code above, that's all contained within the `modal` component.  Example: `onClick={modalCloseAction}` dispatches everything as expected

Comment: ok, well the main difference between the one that works and the one that doesn't is one appears to be trying to leverage `reduxMulti` (not a package I'm familiar with), but I'll have a look at the docs and check if you are doing things the correct way, I presume you don't have any other `reduxMulti` actions that do work in your app?

Comment: @James Taking reduxMulti out of the equation and doing a simple standard return still doesn't work - `return { type: MODAL_OPEN };`.  But yes, I do!  They all work as expected, which is why I'm not sure that's where the problem lies

Comment: @James Here's a working example of `thunk` and `reduxMulti` working together if it helps? https://codesandbox.io/s/reactredux-g02cp

Comment: in fact, I take it back - I thought the issue was you were dispatching two plain actions in your working example but in your actual code you were dispatching one plain and one async. However, I've just verified that this indeed works in your code example :/ the issue is strange, I can't really reproduce the problem, I've debugged `thunk` and `reduxMulti` and they work as expected, I suggest you do the same, it's clearly going wrong at some point but from your code I can't see where.

Comment: @James I've fully recreated my logic, in a super simple way here: https://codesandbox.io/s/reactredux-4yx2m and it works perfectly fine...  Currently blaming the component we consumed...  Thanks for your help all the same!!